# Is there anything in HttpServletRequest what I can use to identify node in a cluster?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, httprequest

How can I identify node within a cluster using info in HttpServletRequest?

Any info which is unique for each node is suitable - I need it to distinguish logs.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to get the `IP` and `hostname`

```
// Get client's IP address
String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr(); // ip

// Get client's hostname
String hostname = request.getRemoteHost(); // hostname
```

If it did not give what you want, I would print all the request header and see if there is a unique identifier

for example, some servers would add `x-forwarded-for` or `X_FORWARDED_FOR` if the request go through proxy

Answer (score 1):

Add a system variable with `-Dnode.id=1`, then you can access it with `System.getProperty("node.id")`.

Answer (score 1):

`java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost()` would give you the name of the host that served the request.  Does that get you what you need?